# Message: Undefined variable problems in PHP/CI

Tags: codeigniter

Controllers

```
function view_question(){

    $data['title'] = "Admin | View Question";
    $data['base_url'] = base_url();

    $viewQuestion = $this->questions->view_question();
    $data['question_set'] = $viewQuestion;

    $this->load->view("admin/admin_question_view",$data);

}
```

View

```
<?foreach ($question_set as $b):?>
        <?php 
        var_dump($b);
        die();?>
        <center> bla bla bla ..
```

and I got this error message

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: b

It's work fine in localhost but when I move to server it's got problems

so I try to add $data['b'] = array(); in controller but it's not work

var_dump($b) got this

```
array(0) { }
```

After I check PHP version on server it's different for server; PHP Version 5.2.6 
for localhost; PHP Version 5.3.1.

It's possible about PHP version ?

Any idea ?

Comment: make sure you get data back when you do `$this->questions->view_question()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you still get data if you just do

```
print_r($question_set);
```

Or perhaps short tags are off? Try using

```
<?php ?>
```

everywhere instead?

Comment: Ok Thanks PHP Version 5.2.6 have problems with <? ?> php short tag